# Unauthorized laravel api call at subdomain after successful authentication

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.1

I have my angularjs app on example.com and my laravel app on api.example.com

I modified my htaccess file so I can do cross domain ajax requests,

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With"
</IfModule>
```

and set the domain value in `config/session.php` to `.example.com`

But when I make an api call the middleware response with a 401:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($this->auth->guest()) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 401,
            'message' =>'Unauthorized.'],
            401
        );
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

When I login via `example.com/user/login?username=foo&password=bar` I can pass the middleware without any problems.

Here is my api call

Request:

```
GET /modul HTTP/1.1
Host: api.reko.to
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: http://reko.to
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.86 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://reko.to/modul/all
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2
```

Response

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 17 Nov 2015 11:22:11 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Set-Cookie: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImpWN0E5dEF0cndnXC9YUG52VU1XazlnPT0iLCJ2YWx1ZSI6IkNzY0JlbnlDbkRZNkQ2enpOdUtGaW92T0RIRmhtcHlcL0JyaERHU0V0YnN1bURHVzE4V1ZLam50MTNsaTh3Tm0xVWFZejdnVitYVHlTZ2R5WEw4eTY0QT09IiwibWFjIjoiZWI1ZTM2YjM1YjUxMTgyZmMxZTc5MzQzZWUzYzI0YWY1OGQwNmI5YzI1ZTFhNTZmNzM1MzA2MTM2NGNmNzk4ZiJ9; expires=Tue, 17-Nov-2015 13:22:12 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; domain=.reko.to; httponly
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With
Content-Length: 39
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

Here is my Login:

```
$http.post(apiUrl + 'user/login', $scope.user).success(function(result) {
            $http.get(apiUrl + 'modul').success(function(result) {
               console.log(result);
            });
});
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cookies after you made the change in `config/session.php` so the new session domain can be used?

Comment: Yes, but i dont see any laravel cookies  in the dev tools of my brwoser. But he sends one laravel_session cookie with new api request

Comment: How are you sending the API request? Also the domain on the `laravel_session` cookie must be `.example.com` as configured, make sure it's so.

Comment: The api request is sent from `example.com` to `api.exmaple.com`. This works, but not when I want to check the authentication.

Comment: And how do you handle cookies when the request is returned from the `api` subdomain? Because you need to send back the cookies on subsequent requests for the session to match.

Comment: I updated my question. A cookie is set and send with every api call.

Comment: When you make the login request, you're receiving back cookies in the response within the `Set-Cookie` header. When you make a new request you need to send that cookie back so the API app knows that you're the same guy that made the request and was logged in previously. So you need to add the `Cookie` header with the cookies content you received the last time, when posting new requests. Please post the code that is making API the requests.

Comment: Yeah, I think the problem is the cookie that isn't send with the request. But how can i fix it?

Comment: Try setting `withCredentials` to `true` on the get request: `$http.get(apiUrl + 'modul', { withCredentials: true })`. That should attach the cookies to the request.

Comment: No chance, didnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95351/discussion-between-mimo-and-bogdan).

Comment: Found the solution: need to write `true` instead of `True` in the htaccess file....